# How to get a ProgressBar in an Eclipse Wizard page?

Tags: java, swt, progress-bar, wizard

I am developing wizard pages. In one wizard page there will conversion of files from one framework to other framework will be performed which takes lot of time. So I want to use a `ProgressBar` on this page.

How can I do it?

Note: I am using SWT, I am not using JFace.

Comment: have you looked at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293903/progressbar-using-threads-in-swt

Answer (score 0):

You can't access progress bar directly, but you can execute a long running process in the context of the wizard dialog and update progress via [progress monitor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.html).

```
IWizardPage page = ...;
IRunnableWithProgress runnable = new IRunnableWithProgress() {
    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.beginTask("Working on 100 units", 100);
        ...
    }
};
page.getWizard().getContainer().run(true, true, runnable);
```